# Check-ins to TFS2013 source control triggers CI build associated with separate TFS Git Repository

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I have a **TFS 2013 server** with several TFS team project collections and developers working happily against them. The project collections have a set of **TFS builds** associated, including relevant CI builds which trigger on each check-in, or in some cases, rolling (accumulated) check-ins. This process works flawlessly and has been the way of working for several years.

Recently, we've introduced a **Git repository** into the mix which *also* sits on our TFS 2013 server and appears as a node that I can connect to from my development environment when I connect to my TFS 2013 server. (i.e. it's not a local repo...)

This is being used by a different set of developers all using VS2013 and (mostly) the Git integration that is part of Team Explorer under VS2013.

This is all working fabulously **EXCEPT**..... team 1 are checking into **TFS source control** and triggering CI builds that I have set up against the Git repository?. Every single commit by any of team 1 is causing the build to trigger, despite the fact that they are modifying code that is NOT part of the Git repo, has never been and never will be!
I've had to fall back to "manual" builds for now, which is not ideal because I really need to have a CI build to run tests.

In terms of the process template, we are using a slight modification to the standard Git build template which I think was derived from the work done by the ALM rangers - the modification is an extra step to trigger an InRelease deployment. I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but in the interest of being detailed on the issue....

Anybody got any ideas of how I can fix this? In essence, I want to isolate the TFS and Git source control entirely when it comes to the builds that are triggered.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Ever find a solution?

Comment: No I'm afraid not. I can only suggest and recommend taking Git outside of TFS! Use GitHub. In this instance, we had to use rolling builds and frequency restrictions.

Comment: If only ~gazes longingly out the window~ 
Thank you, SpaceBison!

Comment: Yeah - it's always the way. So - I'd setup it up as a rolling build, instead of a CI build - and say "build no more than once every 30/60/90 mins" - this means it will still (unfortunately) trigger off of random irrelevant checkins, but it will not trigger off *every* random irrelevent checkin :-)

Comment: what is the source mapping for the offending build? is it narrow enough to only include the git repo mappings?

Comment: @SpaceBison is this still a problem? Can you post your source mappings for both builds?

Comment: Hi @WouterdeKort - no, not anymore, have long since switched to git and github!

Comment: @SpaceBison ok that's a shame! Not that Github is bad :) The Git support in TFS however is getting better and better. Wondered if this was a bug...

Comment: I'm certain it WAS a bug, but this was sometime ago when Git integration was still rather immature....so it's highly likely to not be a problem anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkins to TFVC Team Projects trigger builds in Git Team Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362951/checkins-to-tfvc-team-projects-trigger-builds-in-git-team-project)

Comment: @jessehouwing My post was first, so the other is a duplicate of this if anything. This is also now close to 2.5 years old.....

Comment: The other has an answer, this one doesn't.

Comment: Right, but there's no guarantee that solves it and the age of this post and subsequent irrelevance of the situation nowadays means I can't test their proposition..... so I can't say either way. I'm not sure it can be consolidated.

Comment: Then simply delete it. If it's no longer relevant, can't be tested nor reproduced, then if is better to just remove it and reduce the noise.

Comment: On a hunch I would have guessed that maybe he used a (TFVC) source control path in the build controller for custom build artifacts. Since these would get used by Git-Builds also, that would be a possible explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Other people have already communicated this with Microsoft and found that this is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32262306/675826)

My suggestion would be to upgrade you're server to the latest version. If the problem resides, contact Microsoft Support.