# Checkins to TFVC Team Projects trigger builds in Git Team Project

Tags: git, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, tfvc

I have a TFS project set up for continuous integration. My problem is that checkins on other TFS projects are triggering builds of my project even when no change has been made to my project.

It seems to be related to my project being a Team Foundation Git repository, and none of the other projects are.

Where can I look to find out what's triggering this build?

Edit: To be more clear, what I mean is that I have entirely separate Team Projects. All of them but one use Team Foundation Version Control except one which uses Git. Somehow, checkins on the TFVC Team Projects trigger a build on the Git Team Project

Comment: Checkins against TFVC are triggering builds against the Git repo? Now **that** is an interesting wrinkle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our case, this was identified as a bug in TFS by Microsoft.

The **ServerItem** column in **tbl_BuildDefinitionMapping** for the appropriate build was set to "$\".

The fix I got from Microsoft was to change that to something that doesn't exist like:

> $\GIT_NOTAFOLDER\

This resolved the issue for me.

You need to look up the build definition in **tbl_builddefinition.**  Once you ave found it, remember the **DataspaceId**.

Then open **tbl_builddefinitionmapping** and look for the **DataspaceId** from above.  You should see that the **ServerItem** is **$\**.  Change this to **$\GIT_NOTAFOLDER\** and it should resolve the issue.

Comment: I could not find a DataspaceId anywhere in the database using sys.columns (TFS Version 12.0.31101.0), but I did find that in tbl_BuildDefinitionMapping, my project with the git repo was assigned to the same workspaceId as the other projects that trigger the build.

Comment: The $\GIT_NOTAFOLDER\ workaround you mentioned works, and doesn't appear to have affected our build in any other way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The build will be triggered any time a file is changed in any mapped folders of that build definitions workspace.

I'm guessing you have the build def's workspace mapped to broadly.  You should only include the folders/files that your build needs (and only changes to those files will trigger your build).

[image]

Comment: Since it's a git repo, my source settings tab doesn't have a "Working Folders" section: http://i.imgur.com/NcvnHTE.png . I tried it after removing "refs/heads/*", but it didn't make a difference.  Is there another way to change the workspace?

Comment: (Upvoted for being useful, but this doesn't solve my problem.)

Answer (score 0):

CI builds on Git repository always monitor the whole repository. The only filter you may add is to monitor some branches, but you cannot 'cloak' folders or files as you could with classic TFVC.

Comment: It seems that the problem is more that it's monitoring folders *outside* the repository. Unless you mean repository as this project plus all the non-git projects stored on the TFS server? I have products A and B which use TFS, and product C uses git. Whenever someone checks in on products A or B, C decides to build.

Comment: Do you mean Team Projects that use TFVC as the source system, or other .proj's within the same Git repository?

Comment: I mean checkins to other Team Projects which use TFVC are triggering my Git Team Project to build.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this by deleting the workspaces on the TFS build agent using a tool called TFS Sidekick. After recreating the build definitions, builds on other products no longer triggered builds on the product in Git.

I'm still not sure how they were linked.

Comment: I thought this fixed it, but it didn't. Seems someone else is having this problem too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906809/check-ins-to-tfs2013-source-control-triggers-ci-build-associated-with-separate-t